# kotlin specification nulable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to use Spring Boot 2.0.3 with IntelliJ IDEA.
Kotlin version is 1.2.51.

When I use `jsr305=strict` compile option, I got error at `where` and `and` part.

```
import com.example.spring_boot.domain.task.Task
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification

object TaskSpecification {
    private fun nameContain(name: String?): Specification<Task>? {
        return name?.let {
            Specification { root, query, cb ->
                cb.like(root.get<String>("name"), name)
            }
        }
    }

    fun createSearchSpecification(name: String?
    ): Specification<Task> {
        return Specification.
            where(nameContain(name)).and(nameContain(name))
    }
}
```

It says "Type Mismatch: Required: Specification, Found: Specification?",
and when I changed them to `where(nameContain(name)!!)` and `and(nameContain(name))!!`, the errors disappeared.

Then I got a question.
I saw the 2 method declarations.
Parameters of both methods, `where` and `and`, looks not being NotNull type.
Why did I got such error?

Here, I attached declaration images.

[image: where declaration image],
[image: and declaration image]

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `nameContain(String?)` returns `Specification<Task>?` (nullable) which is not a valid parameter for `where(Specification<T>)` (not-nullable).

Using `return name?.let {... }` means your function will return `null` in case of `name` being null.

Comment: Why is `Specification<Task>?` not valid parameter? According to `where` declaration, the parameter looks nullable. There is no annotation `@Nonnull` or `@NotNull` for it.

Comment: @KenjiOtsuka maybe it has to do with your `strict` flag? I don't know much about this compile option, but maybe it forces all non-annotated parameters as non-nulls? If you can modify `where` method, add `@Nullable` to the parameter to see if it fixes it.